# How does Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>{}) work?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dispatcher

Whenever I get a Invalid-CrossThread-Access error in my windows phone project, I execute my code inside `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {})` and everything works fine after that. However I never clearly understood the meaning of it.

Can someone put some light on it giving detailed explanation on how does it resolves my cross thread errors and what each of its parts mean. As far as I have googled for it, it is used to execute some code on UI thread.

But what are deployment, current, and dispatcher objects. How else can I use them.
TIA

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in the design of the Windows platform. You can't change the user interface (specifically Win32 objects) from another thread then the objects are created from.

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` executes the delegate provided as parameter on the UI thread, not on the thread it is called from.

`Deployment.Current` is a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) reference to the current running application, the `Dispatcher` is the part of the program that is responsible for passing messages around. `BeginInvoke` the method that does actually finds the right thread and executes the delegate.

The difference between `BeginInvoke` and `Invoke` it that the first is ran asynchronously. `Invoke` is executed immediately and execution is suspended until the method finishes.

Comment: I think it's necessary to explain the difference between `BeginInvoke` and `Invoke`

Comment: Okay. But at a place I was trying to access App resources by using `App.Current.Resources` where I have defined resources to be used repeatedly. But this also gave cross thread access error. And putting it inside the current dispatcher resolved the issue. Can you please explain this behaviour. App resources should be something accessible from all parts of the code. Also its something that's not the part of the UI. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't think Windows is unique in having this restriction.

Comment: @david.pfx: I am not familiar with other OS on this matter. Thanks for the info.